# Git : How to merge the changes from a closed pull request?

Tags: git, github

Few weeks back, I had a pull request (PR) against my branch `my:abc` from `them:xyz`.

As of today, the PR is closed.
In the PR, `them:xyz` is now replaced with `unknown repository`, wanted to know what does it mean, how can it happen?

Now I wanted to merge those changes, but unfortunately I cannot contact the other guy to get a new PR (who made the pull request).

But I still have the pull request (which is good).
Is there any way those changes can be merged or cherry-picked ?

Note : PR belongs to commercial company, so cannot share it here.

Comment: Can you add a link to the PR?

Comment: cannot share PR as it belongs to commercial company

Comment: Can you still use `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME`, where the `ID` is the PR's ID? See https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Answer (score 3):

You can always cherry-pick any commit.
Once you commit something to git and you still have branch, the content will remain under git unless you remove it with `git gc` for example

In your case its much more simple, you have the branch and you have the code as well (PR = full changes) so you can use `cherry-pick` or simply add the code from the PR to your branch.

You can always try to set the PR to be merged in to your new branch as well.

---

#### General comment

All github pull request are stored on your repository as well once you clone it.
It is store inside your .git folder next to the ref folder so you have it locally as well.

```
// get locally the ID pull request
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the pull request on GitHub, you can download the pull request as a patch from GitHub, merge locally, and then push the changes.

From the GitHub pull request page:

> **Merging via command line**
>
> If you do not want to use the merge button or an automatic merge
>   cannot be performed, you can perform a manual merge on the command
>   line. Patch
>
> Step 1: From your project repository, check out a new branch and test
>   the changes.
>
> ```
> git checkout -b new-branch master
> curl https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY/pull/1.patch | git am
> ```
>
> Step 2: Merge the changes and update on GitHub.
>
> ```
> git checkout master
> git merge --no-ff new-branch git push
> origin master
> ```

Comment: Looks to be good way, but I got stuck in merge conflict [git am 1.patch], and git status -uno is not helping me out to know the conflicts, it says everything is upto date

Comment: Sometimes it's better to apply patch to the same commit which it was based on, so that there is no conflict, and resolve confluct during merge or cherry-pick, because rezolution there is more convenient

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue a couple of days ago

in my case, the PR that i want to access is another person fork and it currently not exists, So cant pull from his fork directly "currently not exist"

so I handled it by doing the following steps

**Solution :-**

1- i accessed the pull request from the browser it self with `.batch` extension
https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxx/pull/123.patch

this will be redirect to a file with a token in path something like that
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/xxxx/xxx/pull/123.patch?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

2-then i used the command to download this .batch at the project directory
`curl -O https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/xxxx/xxx/pull/123.patch?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

note O  in capital case

this will download the file will be something like that
123.patch_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

3- i applied the changes that exists at this file using `git apply`  with adding `.patch` extension
`git apply 123.patch_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.patch`

at this step  have the changes at you local machine you can then add & commit them

`git add .`

`git commit -m "merging 123 PR "`

Note:
remember to delete the .patch file we actually didn't want to push it at the PR

that all,